# Keeping Floated Navigation Elements on One Line

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm building an 'interactive' that will be displayed on a touch screen. One of the features is a fixed footer navigation. I am using floats for the main navigation elements and within each element, there is a picture and text which are being displayed side by side by floating the picture to the left.

I have it working for the most part but I have a few issues:

1. When the viewport is below the touchscreen width (1366px), the floated navigation elements stack up on top of one another. I know this is standard behavior but I'd like to keep them on one line and fixed even when the viewport is smaller (scrollbar ok).
2. The elements of the nav bar must maintain their position (for each element, there is a picture and text which must remain side by side, not on top of eachother)
3. The requirements state that when active, each element must have a border around it, be bolded, and uppercased. This jams up my fixed width elements. I've kludged it together such that the fixed widths contain enough space to accommodate the increase in size from the bolding and the uppercasing but I'd love to not have to worry about this.

I tried white-space: nowrap; but that ruined the formatting of the nav elements.

Here is the HTML for the navigation (yes, I'm using inline styles while I tweak and I know it's horrible). Unfortunately, to get the elements to align properly, they all need different fixed widths. Any ideas on this would be awesome.

```
<div style="background-color: white !important" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <ul class="nav" style="background-color:white !important; max-width: 1366px; ">
        <li class="" style="padding-top:0px; width:110px;">
           <a class="bootstrap-override" style="background-color: white; box-shadow: none !important; -moz-box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/title"><img src="img/logo-nav-bar.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li style="width:200px; padding-top:10px;" class="active" >
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/vignette">
                <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-1.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Indigenous Traditions</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:176px;">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="#">
                <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-2.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Industrial Embroidery</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:156px;" >
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="#">
               <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-3.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Modern American Silks</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:192px;">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/beller">
               <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-4.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">American Made Fashion</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:142px;">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/batiks">
               <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-5.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Modern American Batiks</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:118px;">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="#">
               <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-6.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Art in Dress</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:140px;">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/tea_gowns">
               <img class="bardnav-item-image nav-img" src="img/icon-7.png">
                <p class="bardnav-item-text">Tea Gowns</p>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li style="width:1px;">
            <img src="img/border.png">
        </li>
        <li style="width:98px; padding-top:0px">
            <a class="bootstrap-override" href="/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/about_main">
               <img style="margin-top:10px;" src="img/link-red.png">
                <h5 style="max-width:100px;">About the Exhibition</h5>
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bardnav-item-text{
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.active{
    color: #8B0E04 !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd2cc;
     border-right: 5px solid #ddd2cc;
    border-left: 5px solid #ddd2cc;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;       
}

.active > a > p{
    color: #8B0E04 !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.nav > li{
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
}

.about-active{
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;

}
 .bootstrap-override{
    background-color: white !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;

}

.nav-img{
    float:left;
}
```

You can see the page live at [this link](http://evanmrose.co/projects/dev/mediacombo/public) (click the page, click on "indigenous traditions" at the title page to see what I'm talking about)

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried using Fittext or a responsive text plugin that supports images? That should be the best way for you to control this behaviour.
2. You should *float* both text and image to the *left* and add a clear div:

   .clear{clear:both;}
3. You can reuse the Fittext or a responsive text plugin to control this with *if* statements or you can initially attach a *padding* to the elements and swap the *padding* space with the *border*, when active.

Comment: Thanks, will try shortly